# How to deal the problem "Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit; "?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
public class A{
    @Async
    public void methodA(){
        someService.methodB();
    }
}

public class someServiceImpl implements someService{

    @Transactional(noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void methodB(){

        try{

        //to do
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

For example, I used the '@ Transactional' to mark my method hope to commit the transaction when error happened.But the problem still happened like this:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.linkyoyo.wmlink.service.impl.DataShowScheduleComputeServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9ee37ac.computeAvgIntegrityRate(<generated>)
    at com.linkyoyo.wmlink.schedule.ComputeDataShowService.computeAllFunction(ComputeDataShowService.java:119)
    at com.linkyoyo.wmlink.schedule.ComputeDataShowService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f85885cb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

How can I deal this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing your service calls some other component that is annotated with `@Transactional`, correct? If an exception occurs when calling this other component and is caught in `SomeServiceImpl` you will be faced with the exception you describe when the transaction system attempts to commit the transaction in `methodB`. Any exception passing an `@Transactional` boundary will mark the surrounding transaction as rollback-only, unless you have explicitly told the system otherwise.

If you want the surrounding transaction (i.e. the transaction created for `methodB`) to "survive" this exception, you'll need to alter the `@Transactional` annotation on the *target* component (i.e. the component where the Exception is thrown) with `noRollbackFor`.

Comment: Yes. I call other service's method in the methodB, and it throws exception. I catch the exception in methodB. So if the other service's method throw the exception, the transaction will be marked by rollback only? You mean I should use the annotation for the method which I called in the methodB?

Comment: Yes, the noRollbackFor needs to be placed on the method you call from methodB